# Where to buy Mamarei Hadracha LeKalos

Tags: jewish-books, wedding

Where can one purchase Rabbi Wolbe's Hadracha Mussar book for Kallos. I see the Chassan one floating around but can't seem to find the one for Kallos.

Comment: I found it in a regular *seforim* store in America. Where have you been looking?

Comment: Can you give me names? im in NY.

Comment: You could enquire of baishamussar@gmail.com

Comment: I found it in Baltimore. I'm sure you can find it in NY...

Answer (score 2):

[Zundel Berman Books](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%A1-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%94) has it in stock. You can order online.

Comment: @Meir: Thanks...